# Performance difference between STL vector pushback and set value

Tags: c++, stl, vector, performance

I have an array, say ARR, and the total number of objects in ARR is known.
I want to copy (put) an attribute of each object in ARR into an STL vector, say VEC.

One way is to iterate through ARR

```
VEC.pushback(ARR[i].att);
```

The other way is

```
VEC.resize(ARR.size());
VEC[i] = ARR[i].att;
```

Do them make difference regarding runtime performance? Which one is better? Thanks.

FOLLOW-UP: I would like to provide some experiment results for anyone interested.
I tried (1) resize() + '=' and (2) reserve() + push_back() methods by putting 50000 integers into an STL vector.

```
(1) takes 0.000201s;
(2) takes 0.000229s.
```

- Both were compiled with g++ -O3, and I ran the program several times.
- (1) outperforms (2) consistently.
- (1) has extra allocations, thus taking slightly more memory in terms of space.

Comment: This is a bad question - you could answer it yourself simply by measuring. Asking *which is better* is always subjective.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Why is it subjective? I would like the code to be running fast, not only for myself.

Comment: @jason.Z Use `push_back` or `emplace_back` then. It's more idiomatic. Only worry about performance of such things after profling.

Comment: @Pubby yes, I was writing that code, and just need an quick answer to clear my concern.

Comment: @jason.Z: It's subjective because relative performance is depending on compiler and library in use, and all anybody could do would be to measure individual compiler / library implementations. Anyway, Nim pointed out the way to go: `reserve()` the necessary space to avoid resizing, then use `push_back()`. "Setting" (using `operator[]`) always carries the potential for index out of range errors.

Comment: @jason.Z: Your wording is subjective - there is no definite answer to the question *"Which is better?"*, because *good* and *bad* are subjective. As for performance, if you want to know which is faster, just go and measure - it is the only reliable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `resize()` (or `reserve()`) before may potentially save some resizing as you add new items. Anyway, you already know the number of items, so it makes even more sense.

With `resize()` you will have a default construct step, I'd go with `reserve()` to prevent reallocations and `push_back()` (and in C++11, `emplace_back()` if your compiler supports it)

Comment: so the second one is better?

Comment: Test it for yourself - but as a guess, I would say so - instead of the `resize()` though, try the `reserve()` followed by `push_back()` or the other function as I mention - you may get slightly better numbers.

Comment: I did some experiments just now. See the follow-ups above :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with QueryPerformanceCounter() function or start a timer before execution and stop after execution in both scenarios.
You can see the difference in time and can evaluate how much time each scenario takes and then decide which one is better solution..

Answer (score 0):

If you want copy array's data to vector you could simply do VEC.assign(ARR, ARR + ARR_size)
if ARR is a simple array, or VEC.assign(ARR.begin(), ARR.end()) if arr is any other sequence
That would be the fastest way for non-POD type